# facebook page plugin - like event not firing

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this IFRAME tag on my page:

```
        <iframe id="poptinSocialIframe" class="poptin-socia-iframe" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/www.popt.in/&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=214&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&tabs=false&appId=1487135378023653" width="340" height="214" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And i set this in the javascript section:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
        appId      : '1079697562162278',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.9',
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    like()
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));   

function like(){
    console.info('leaded');
    try{
        var page_like_or_unlike_callback = function(url, html_element) {
          console.log("page_like_or_unlike_callback");
          console.log(url);
          console.log(html_element);
        }

        // In your onload handler
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
    }catch(err){
        console.info(err);
    }
}
```

The iframe is working. But when i click the "like button" the event not firing
Please help!!!!

Comment: why do you put the FB.Event.subscribe calls in a separate function? you  can just put them in the fbAsyncInit callback. you only need them on page load anyway.

Comment: try this directly in the fbAsyncInit function: FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', (url) => {console.log(url);});

Comment: Pretty sure that the events are for the like button. Not the page plugin. Why do you need to know if someone clicks the button anyway?

Comment: because i'm providing a service that customer can enter there page url and i will send them email if someone like the page.